# How to make a Vuetify rule async and await with a ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js, axios, vuetify.js

I am using Vuetify form validation to check an input field, and I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to call a ajax get call and make it await so that I can use the result in a rule?

I've attempted it below, but it doesn't seem to work!

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      rules: {
        isLocationNew: value => {

          if (value == '' || value == null || value.length <= 1) {
            this.validLocation = false;
            return 'Invalid length.';
          }

          this.validLocation = true;

          var hasName = this.newLocationNameSearch(value);
          if (hasName) {
            return 'Location name already exists.';
          } else {
            return true;
          }
        }
      },


      // down in methods
      methods: {
        async newLocationNameSearch(text) {
          if (text == '' || text == null || text.length <= 1) {
            return false;
          }

          await axios.get('/api/Locations/HasLocationName', {
            params: {
              text: text,
              jobsiteId: this.jobsiteId
            }
          }).then(response => {
            return response.data;
          }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error)
          })

        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a better solution, as I needed to perform a check similar to checking another email address in the database. So I used 'error-messages'

like this

> @input="newLocationNameSearch($event)" :error-messages="newLocationErrorMessages"

this way every character that is input will be checked in 'newLocationNameSearch()' and I fill and remove items from 'newLocationErrorMessages' to display to the user!

Answer (score 0):

`newLocationNameSearch` Is an async function. Async functions return promises, so when you write

```
var hasName = this.newLocationNameSearch(value);
```

hasName is set to a promise, which is always truthy.

You need something like:

```
    isLocationNew: async value => {

      if (value == '' || value == null || value.length <= 1) {
        this.validLocation = false;
        return 'Invalid length.';
      }

      this.validLocation = true;

      var hasName = await this.newLocationNameSearch(value);
      if (hasName) {
        return 'Location name already exists.';
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }
```

And remember that wherever isLocationNew is called, it will need to be awaited as well.

Furthermore, the `newLocationNameSearch` method does not actually return a value when awaited.

```
      await axios.get('/api/Locations/HasLocationName', {
        params: {
          text: text,
          jobsiteId: this.jobsiteId
        }
      }).then(response => {
        return response.data;
      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error)
      })
```

Has the return statement inside the callback for the `.then()` call. The `newLocationNameSearch` then doesn't return anything, meaning it returns `undefined`, which is falsy.

The good new is that async/await means we don't have to bother with `then` callbacks anymore.

We can instead write

```
try {
     var response = await axios.get('/api/Locations/HasLocationName', {
        params: {
          text: text,
          jobsiteId: this.jobsiteId
        }
      });

      return response.data;

} catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
}
```

Comment: so I still need to keep the async and await in the method call and the axios call as well?

Comment: Yes, and actually I've noticed another error in the original code. Async/await can be tricky at first. Edit incoming.

Comment: yes I'm realizing that now. I'm gettting an error that says "vuetify.js:25169 [Vuetify] Rules should return a string or boolean, received 'object' instead"

Comment: @user1186050 Ah, you're using vuetify... that may change things

Comment: @user1186050 Yeah vuetify doesn't support async validation out of the box. There's a feature request for it on [github](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/4231), otherwise you could try using the workaround suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49132167/how-to-validate-vuetify-text-field-asynchronously)

Comment: so then whats the best way to validate a text field when I need to check against the database? ex. a email address!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
methods: {
  fetchUserData: async function() {
      const response = await fetch(
            "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"
      );
      this.users = await response.json();
}
```

You can use it like this example.