# How to use async/ await in vuetify rules without error "Rules should return a string or boolean, received 'object' instead"?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a email rule where the user input email cannot be in the current database (has to be new user). Thus, I need to query the database upon user input, but if I use async await in the rule, i get this error "Rules should return a string or boolean, received 'object' instead". But if i dont use async/await, then I get a promise returned instead. How do i ensure that checkRegisteredUser() returns the desired true/ false values before proceeding with the validation?

Rule:

```
 emailRule: [
       v => {
            const emails =  v ? v.join(','): '';
            const emailArray=emails.split(',')
            const invalidEmails = emailArray.filter(email =>
                !/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(email.trim())
            );
            let status = v ? this.checkRegisteredUser(v): ''
            if (invalidEmails.length > 0) {
              return status !== false
                ? 'Input field contains registered and invalid email address(es).'
                : 'Input field contains invalid email address(es).';
            } else if (status) {
              return 'Input field contains registered email address(es).';
            }
             return true;
        },
      ],
```

Call api to query from database (if user found then return true, else return false):

````
 async checkRegisteredUser(email){
      let username=email.slice(-1)[0]
      try {
       return  await this.$fetch({
          method: 'GET',
          url: 'api/info_management/users/getByUsername',
          params: {
             username
          }
        }).then((response) =>{
          return Object.keys(response.data).length !== 0;
        }
        );
      } catch (error) {
        log(error);
      }
    },
    ```
````

Comment: IMO, Vuetify rules should be used to validate the user input at the front end only. And rules are mostly used to check whether user input is validated enough to process at the backend. In order to validate data from the backend you must send a request and handle the backend response. This should not be done using Vuetify rules.

Comment: The question isn't specific enough. Vuetify 3 seems to supports async validators while 2 doesn't

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49132167/how-to-validate-vuetify-text-field-asynchronously